# Problem setting min and max date on x axis in Apex chart

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, apexcharts

I have 6 month (9 Oct 2022 to 6 Apr 2023) financial data but I want show only 3 months or 1 month data on chart.

I am trying to set min date ("2023-01-05") and max date ("2023-04-05") in option xaxis: { min : , max : } on chart but it is not working

How to set 3 month or 1 month data on chart?

[Reproduce link](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-worker-6vevbm?file=/src/components/ApexSyncCharts.tsx:203-215) on codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

You can define min and max dates in the xaxis config by using millisecond timestamps as detailed here - https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/#min 
 Example:

```
chart: {
   ...chart config code here
},
xaxis: {
   min: new Date('2023-01-05').getTime(),
   max: new Date('2023-04-05').getTime(),
}
```

It is worth noting however that if you have the toolbar enabled with the "reset" option, this button will reset the zoom out to the full six months and ignore your min and max values. These are only used as on load defaults. If that's an issue you can hook up a custom button to handle a reset back to these same values, using the zoomX() method documented here - https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/